# bufferWriter can not write in new line

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working with java file and I want to write a text into file but it doesn't go to new line. How can I write in new line with bufferWriter?

```
public void setData() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("SchoolDB.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        School school = new School();
        school = allSchools.get(j);
        //set name
        bufferedWriter.write(school.getName());
        //houses
        if(school.getHoused())
            for(int i = 0; i < school.getHouses().size(); i++)
                bufferedWriter.write(school.getHouses().get(i).getName());
        else 
            bufferedWriter.write("0");
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        //courses 
        if(school.getHouses().size() != 0)
            for(int i = 0; i < school.getCourses().size(); i++)
                bufferedWriter.write(school.getCourses().get(i).getName());
        else 
            bufferedWriter.write("0");
        //students
        if(school.getNumOfStudents() != 0)
            for(int i = 0; i < school.getStudents().size(); i++)
                bufferedWriter.write(school.getStudents().get(i).getName());
        else 
            bufferedWriter.write("0");
        //professors
        if(school.getProfessor().size() != 0)
            for(int i = 0; i < school.getProfessor().size(); i++)
                bufferedWriter.write(school.getProfessor().get(i).getName());
        else 
            bufferedWriter.write("0");
        // '*'   :)
        bufferedWriter.write("*");
    }
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

it's working correctly but I can't write in new line
by the way, these methods I Tried and didn't work:

1. I closed the file.
2. \n
3. \n\r
4. bufferWriter.newLine();

and the output is like this: 
''HogwartsGryffindorHufflepuffRavenclawSlytherin
FlyingPotions0Minerva McGonagolSeverus Snape*Beauxbatons0
00Olympe Maxime*Durmstrang0
00Igor Karkaroff*IlvermornyHorned SerpentWampusThunderbirdPukwudgie
Defense Against the Dark ArtsCharms0Rionach Steward*Koldovstoretz0
000*''.
it didn't separate in the first line

Solved: 
I think it was a problem with the tab I run this code. I was in service tab. I run this code in main tab and it worked.
note: I just changed tab. in main I had a object of this class.

Comment: What is your input, your expected output and your actual output?

Comment: I have a service test in which, I initialize a Vector<School> and I want to write their names.

Comment: it correctly working but I can't write in new line

Comment: You are already calling`BufferedWriter.newLine()`, and that is exactly what it does. `\n\r` isn't a recognised line terminator, but `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n` are.  Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: yes I wrote it,but it doesn't work in my code. that is the question itself

Comment: It works for everybody else. What output are you seeing, and what output are you expecting, and how are you viewing the output?

Comment: It works perfectly. What exactly do you mean "it doesn't work"? Maybe your input school is null and you get a NPE?

Comment: Please format your edt so that it corresponds with what you really see, and answer my three questions.

Comment: input is a vector of some objects.

Comment: I want to write name of fields in that objects, first name in line 1 and others in line 2

Comment: but it write all names in line 1

Comment: the post is edited

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just say

> ***bufferedWriter.write("\n");***

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedWriter.newLine();
```

is the platform-independent way to add a newline. When you say you don't get a newline, what do you mean? How do you open `SchoolDB.txt`? Did you try a hex viewer to see the actual characters? Are you creating it in one OS (e.g Linux) but checking it in another with a different idea about newlines (e.g Windows)?

In any case, on Linux try

```
xxd SchoolDB.txt
```

and look for `0a` characters (unix-style EOL) vs `0d0a` (Windows-style CRLF). If you only have `0a` as the EOL marker then on Windows you may see it as one line.

Comment: I use windows 8.1.

Comment: I have oped it. after these codes I have just one line filled with proper names. it seems that the only thing that didn't work properly is the bufferWriter.newLine();